# Android - ListView Cells are adding more ImageViews when scrolling ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a layout that defines the way the Cells look in my ListView, but when i scroll the only part of the Cell that changes when i scroll are the ImageViews which sit inside the LinearLayout View.

What should happen is that there should only be 5 stars displayed inside this LinearLayout but when i scroll i get loads of these star images inside my LinearLayout when only 5 stars should be displayed.

This is my Custom Array Adapter:

```
public class ThreadArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ThreadObj> {


        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        public ArrayList<ThreadObj> data = null;

        public ThreadArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ThreadObj> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        //WeatherHolder holder = null;
        ThreadHolder t = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            //TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadTitle);
            //t = new ThreadObj(tv.getText().toString());

            t = new ThreadHolder();
            //holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            t.threadUsernameTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadUsername);
            t.threadDateTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadDate);
            t.threadRatingIV = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadRating);
            t.threadTitleTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadTitle);
            t.threadCategoryTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadCategory );
            t.threadSubCategoryTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadSubCategory);
            t.threadCountryTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadCountry);
            t.threadStarLL = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.threadStarContainer);
            t.threadFlagIV = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadFlag);

            row.setTag(t);
        }
        else
        {
            t = (ThreadHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        ThreadObj thread = data.get(position);
        t.threadUsernameTV.setText(thread.firstname + " " + thread.lastname);
        t.threadDateTV.setText(thread.date);
        t.threadTitleTV.setText(thread.title);
        t.threadCategoryTV.setText(thread.category);
        t.threadSubCategoryTV.setText(thread.subCategory);
        t.threadCountryTV.setText(thread.country);

        if(thread.ageRating == 4){
            t.threadRatingIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.agerating17);
        }
        else if(thread.ageRating == 3){
            t.threadRatingIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.agerating12);
        }
        else if(thread.ageRating == 2){
            t.threadRatingIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.agerating7);
        }
        else{
            t.threadRatingIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.ageratingpg);
        }
        //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            ImageView star1 = new ImageView(this.context);
            star1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star1);

            ImageView star2 = new ImageView(this.context);
            star2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star2);

            if(i < thread.rating){
            t.threadStarLL.addView(star2);
            }else{
            t.threadStarLL.addView(star1);
            }

        }

        if(thread.flags > 0){
            t.threadFlagIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag2);
        }else{
            t.threadFlagIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag1);
        }


        return row;
        }

        static class ThreadHolder
        {
        //ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView threadUsernameTV;
        TextView threadDateTV;
        ImageView threadRatingIV;
        TextView threadTitleTV;
        TextView threadCategoryTV;
        TextView threadSubCategoryTV;
        TextView threadCountryTV;
        LinearLayout threadStarLL;
        ImageView threadFlagIV;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always creating new `ImageView`s and adding them to the `t.threadStarLL` layout -- even when re-using an existing view.  One way to fix this would be to clear out the `threadStarLL` layout before adding the new stars.

Try adding this line before the `for` loop where you create the stars:

```
t.threadStarLL.removeAllViews();
```